# How should I keep track of which entry to update in the database for my web app?

Tags: javascript, database, web-applications

I'm trying to create a TODO list web app for self-learning purpose. I use JavaScript and PHP.

On client side, my app uses a global variable `list_id` to store the ID of a list that is currently being viewed by user. This ID is the same as the ID stored in the database. So when something is updated on the list by user, it sends `list_id` over to PHP and updates the corresponding entry in the database.

But I noticed that this approach is seriously insecure. Namely, attackers can just update the value of `list_id` in the console of their web browser and they can make modifications to any lists in the database just by changing the value of `list_id`.

How should I prevent this while also keeping track of which list to update in the database?

I suppose I could declare a variable as final/const, but I don't think there is a cross-browser way to do this in JavaScript. Maybe the slightly better way is to declare the ID as a private variable inside a class and make sure that there are no methods that update the variable. What would be the most secure way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use login system, you should check if user session id == owner id of entry and only then allow to edit it.

Comment: Lists on my web app will be freely accessible by more than one person. So your approach probably does not work, does it? They only way for user to protect their list is to set a password. This also relies on `list_id`.

Comment: you cant trust any data that user send. only server data, which sessions are. however, you can log ip of user, if it's not that important to secure your data. user can change ip, but it's not that simple

Comment: I see. So if I can also save `list_id` as a session variable in PHP for each user, it will work, correct? That seems like the way to go unless I am wrong.

Comment: yea, pretty much, just you need to provide session token retrieval functional if user will come to site from another computer. that's what authorization on sites do